# IOS 8 simulator setting fractional digits for location

Tags: location, ios-simulator, ios8

Can not set fractional digits for a location. The location always resets. I have tried

Editing the scheme > Select "Run XXXX.app / Debug" > Select "Allow Location Simulation" and selecting none. After that setting a location from simulator Debug > Location > Custom Location > latitude = 10,001 ; longitude = 10,001 
It always get reset to lat 10 long 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. :)) Apple displays the location with a comma and to input it you have to use a dot for input. So to set the latitude or longitude to 10,001 you will have to write 10.001

NOTE: the ios 7 simulator accepts input only with comma notation. the ios 8 simulator accepts input only with dot notation.